# Convert UTC to CST in NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am getting the following string to be used, but it is from `UTC-0`, and I need to convert it to `CST`.

```
serverdate = @ "2017-07-31 02:18:50";
```

I added the following code, but it returns `nil`

```
NSDateFormatter *dfLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
[dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CST"]];

NSString *time =[dfLocal stringFromDate:serverdate];
NSLog(@"%@", time);
```

I even tried the following options, no luck.. still it returns nil.

```
[dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CDT"]];
```

and tried

```
[df_local setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Chicago"]];
```

Comment: There is no such a time zone called CST.

Comment: `Central Standard Time (CST)` https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst, I even tried `CDT`, same result, it returns `nil`

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766557/nsdateformatter-to-format-server-response-in-mmm-dd-yyyy-format .

Comment: @ElTomato - That question isn't a dupe as it changes format and not the time zone. However there probably is a dupe out there, handling dates produces a lot of questions!

Comment: You have a couple of people giving you the right answer below, but I'm curious as to where your server date is coming from in the first place and why it is a string?

Comment: @WilliamGP It comes from the RESTFUL Api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to handle the seconds in your time:

```
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Next set the timezone to UTC and convert your string:

```
[dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *serverUTC = [dfLocal dateFromString:serverdate];
```

Now change the time zone and convert back to a string:

```
[dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Chicago"]];
NSString *time =[dfLocal stringFromDate:serverUTC];
```

Use `America/Chicago` as that will handle DST correctly.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Try this answer:

```
 NSString *strInputDateString = @"2017-07-31 02:18:50";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    //Set new dateFormate

    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:strInputDateString];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CST"]];

    NSString *strOutputDateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date1];
    NSLog(@"%@",strInputDateString);
    NSLog(@"%@",strOutputDateString);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

1. You actually need to do two separate things here; first, you need to parse the UTC date string you've received from the server into a date, and second, you need to display that date as a string in CST.
2. Your dateFormat does indeed need to include the :ss at the end, as Steven mentioned.
3. If there's not a specific reason that you need CST, but rather the problem is something like this being an internal app for a company that happens to be located in the Central time zone area, then I'd suggest using [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] instead. This allows your app to keep on Just Working™ if somebody suddenly needs to use it somewhere else, and will also automatically handle things like daylight savings.

With all that said, here's some code that should do what you want:

```
NSString *serverdate = @"2017-07-31 02:18:50";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:serverdate];

// [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CST"] should work too
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

NSString *time = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should change your `dateFormat` from `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.